# Make checkboxes checked on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to load the checked state of checkboxes on page load.

For example, previously selected two checkboxes, and saved the data to local storage. When the page is loaded again I want to retrieve the data(already figured this part out), then set the state of the checkboxes to be checked(not yet figured out).

I'm using AgReactGrid. Is there some property of columnDefs where I can use a cellRenderer to do this or some other way?

The Grid:

```
    <AgGridReact 
    rowSelection="multiple"
    onGridReady={params => this.gridApi = params.api}
    enableSorting={true}
    enableFilter={true}
    pagination={true}
    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
    rowData={this.state.rowData}>
    </AgGridReact>
```

State:

```
 this.state = {
            columnDefs: [
                { headerName: 'Checkbox', field: 'check', checkboxSelection: true},
                { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name' }
            ]
```

UpdateSelection:

```
updateSelection = e => {
        const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
        const selectedData = selectedNodes.map(node => node.data);
        const selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedData.map(node => node.name).join(',');
        localStorage.setItem('previouslyChecked', selectedDataStringPresentation );
    }
```

Comment: Providing code helps to solve the issue quickly.

Comment: If it's not something as simple as `document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").checked = window.localStorage.getItem("checkboxValue");` than please include the code related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

fetch the checked status from localStorage on componentDidMount() and set the state of checkbox there only, so that it will render after setting the state annd reflect immediately.